# How to get liquor to build guards in Victoria II?

Tags: victoria-2

I'm playing as Brazil and I have liquor factories. All its output is sold I get no liquor to build Guards. When I issue a Guard recruitment order it stays decades waiting for liquor. Is there any way to prevent that?
The version is 1.3

Answer (score 1):

You can stockpile liquor in National Trade by setting it from auto to manual.